# Gradle ear plugin - intercept each lib file as it's copied

Tags: java, gradle, ear

I have the following build.gradle that produces an EAR file containing one Bean jar, with all the dependencies of that jar in APP-INF/lib.

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
    deploy(group: 'com.mycompany', name: 'MyServiceBean', version: '1.0.1')
    earlib project(path:':MyServiceBean', configuration: 'compile')

}

ear {
    libDirName 'APP-INF/lib'
    deploymentDescriptor {
        initializeInOrder = true
        displayName = "MyServiceEAR"
        description = "Description of the application."
    }
    eachFile { fcd ->
        //this only prints out files in the root of the EAR
        println "Copying file: " + fcd.name
    }
}
```

Some of the files that go in APP-INF/lib contain environment-specific values (not my plan, inherited code that we can't change right now). What I want to do when creating the EAR file is

- loop through each jar that goes into APP-INF/lib as it is copied
- Extract that jar file
- Replace placeholders in certain files with environment-specific values
- Repack that jar file
- Continue putting that new file into APP-INF/lib.

I know how to do the repacking, but I don't know how to loop through the files going into APP-INF/lib.

My eachFile closure only prints out the names of the files that go in the root of the EAR, ie. application.xml and MyServiceBean.jar.

How can I loop through each file in the APP-INF/lib directory?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can achieve this by using ziptree, take a look at https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html and http://fernandorubbo.blogspot.no/2013/06/embedded-war-using-gradle.html

Comment: Can you provide a sample project on GitHub e.g.?